# Kotlin Generics with upper and lower bounds required

Tags: kotlin, generics

I come across a generics problem that I'm struggling with. I've distilled the code down to a simple example to show the problem, as follows

I have a simple hierarchy of types:

```
open class Fruit
class Apple : Fruit() {
    fun crunch(): String = "CRUNCH!"
}

class Orange : Fruit() {
    fun squish(): String = "SQUISH!"
}
```

and a corresponding hierarchy of consumers specific to those types, with a generic parent:

```
abstract class FruitConsumer<T : Fruit> {
    abstract fun consume(fruit: T)
}

class AppleConsumer : FruitConsumer<Apple>() {
    override fun consume(apple: Apple) {
        println("consuming apple ${apple.crunch()}")
    }
}

class OrangeConsumer : FruitConsumer<Orange>() {
    override fun consume(orange: Orange) {
        println("consuming orange ${orange.squish()}")
    }
}
```

I need to be able to process a list of fruit of unknown type using one of these 'consumers' and currently have this:

```
fun processFruit(fruitList: List<Fruit>) {
    fruitList.forEach {
        val processor = consumerFactory(it)
        processor.consume(it)
    }
}

fun <T : Fruit> consumerFactory(theFruit: T): FruitConsumer<T> {
    return when (theFruit) {
        is Apple -> AppleConsumer() as FruitConsumer<T>       <---- unchecked cast
        is Orange -> OrangeConsumer() as FruitConsumer<T>     <---- unchecked cast
        else -> throw RuntimeException()
    }
}
```

This reports unchecked casts for `as FruitConsumer<T>`, but removing these means I have to consider bounds. This then comes with its own problems, e.g.

If I define the return of the factory method as an 'out' type (making it a 'producer' to the kotlin compiler), I don't need the casts:

```
fun processFruit(fruitList: List<Fruit>) {
    fruitList.forEach {
        val processor = consumerFactory(it)
        processor.consume(it)         <--- ERROR HERE
    }
}

fun <T : Fruit> consumerFactory(theFruit: T): FruitConsumer<out Fruit> {
    return when (theFruit) {
        is Apple -> AppleConsumer()      <--- no cast
        is Orange -> OrangeConsumer()    <--- no cast
        else -> throw RuntimeException()
    }
}
```

but then since the return type from the factory is considered a producer, it can't consume anything.

If I change the bounds using the 'in' keyword (to make the return type a 'consumer' to the kotlin compiler), then I can't return the specific consumer types:

```
fun processFruit(fruitList: List<Fruit>) {
    fruitList.forEach {
        val processor = consumerFactory(it)
        processor.consume(it)      <------ This compiles fine now
    }
}

fun <T : Fruit> consumerFactory(theFruit: T): FruitConsumer<in Fruit> {
    return when (theFruit) {
        is Apple -> AppleConsumer()         <--- Error type mismatch
        is Orange -> OrangeConsumer()       <--- Error type mismatch
        else -> throw RuntimeException()
    }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious here? Is there an elegant solution to this without using unchecked casts?

Comment: You cannot avoid unchecked casts here.

Comment: Also, consider making `FruitConsumer` non-generic, and do a *checked* cast with `as` in `consume`.

Comment: @Sweeper wow you are really on it!   I'm glad of the confirmation though, this has been driving me mad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable in a type-safe fashion by:

1. Completing the action on a `Fruit` without returning the respective `FruitConsumer`
2. Defining a method on `Fruit` for the functionality, or
3. Using a visitor pattern to locate the functionality in one place.

##### Completing the action without returning

Here, you can adjust your loop to:

```
fun processFruit(fruitList: List<Fruit>) {
    fruitList.forEach {
        consumeFruit(it)
    }
}

fun consumeFruit(theFruit: Fruit) {
    return when (theFruit) {
        is Apple -> AppleConsumer().consume(theFruit)
        is Orange -> OrangeConsumer().consume(theFruit)
        else -> throw RuntimeException()
    }
}
```

By not returning we have not given ourselves the burden of having two compatible objects together 'in the wild'; then we can write a program that compiles fine<sup>1</sup>.

In addition, there are two other ways that are worthy of consideration in such a situation (although they are essentially using the same theme).

##### A method on `Fruit`

This is probably the most straightforward way, and is really classic OOP and the [*Hollywood principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)<sup>2</sup>. Programs normally simplify when you locate functionality for the same 'thing' in the same place.

Here, define:

```
abstract class Fruit {
    abstract fun beConsumed()
}
```

Then you can have on each `Fruit`:

```
class Apple : Fruit() {
    fun crunch(): String = "CRUNCH!"
    override fun beConsumed() {
        AppleConsumer().consume(this)
    }
}

class Orange : Fruit() {
    fun squish(): String = "SQUISH!"
    override fun beConsumed() {
        OrangeConsumer().consume(this)
    }
}
```

And your loop simply becomes:

```
fun processFruit(fruitList: List<Fruit>) {
    fruitList.forEach {
        it.beConsumed()
    }
}
```

##### Using a visitor pattern

It may not be possible for each `Fruit` to know how it is consumed, or it may be inappropriate for other reasons. Such situations could be when the `FruitConsumer` needs various dependencies<sup>3</sup> or is in a different module.

Then the visitor pattern nicely still allows a type-safe approach. First we need to require `Fruit`s to accept visitors:

```
abstract class Fruit {
    abstract fun accept(visitor: FruitVisitor)
}

interface FruitVisitor {
    fun visit(apple: Apple)
    fun visit(orange: Orange)
}
```

We define our `accept` methods in the usual way:

```
class Apple : Fruit() {
    fun crunch(): String = "CRUNCH!"
    override fun accept(visitor: FruitVisitor) = visitor.visit(this)
}

class Orange : Fruit() {
    fun squish(): String = "SQUISH!"
    override fun accept(visitor: FruitVisitor) = visitor.visit(this)
}
```

Then a visitor is given the knowledge of how to consume the different `Fruit` types:

```
class FruitConsumerVisitor : FruitVisitor {
    override fun visit(apple: Apple) {
        AppleConsumer().consume(apple)
    }

    override fun visit(orange: Orange) {
        OrangeConsumer().consume(orange)
    }
}
```

And finally we update our loop:

```
fun processFruit(fruitList: List<Fruit>) {
    val fruitVisitor = FruitConsumerVisitor()
    fruitList.forEach {
        it.accept(fruitVisitor)
    }
}
```

To wrap it up, I've put this solution on a [Kotlin playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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) with a main method so we can see it in action:

```
fun main() {
    processFruit(listOf(Apple(), Orange(), Apple()))
}

// Prints:
// consuming apple CRUNCH!
// consuming orange SQUISH!
// consuming apple CRUNCH!
```

---

<sup>1</sup>For completeness, you might consider improving this further by making `Fruit` a sealed class to avoid the `else` in the `when`. If this is not possible, then one of the other methods is more appropriate as the compiler will not allow you to extend the `Fruit` family without prescribing how the new fruit is consumed.

<sup>2</sup>*"Don't call us, we'll call you"*

<sup>3</sup>Although that could be overcome by passing in the dependencies needed to construct any `FruitConsumer` instance in the `beConsumed` method.

Comment: Thanks @Simon Jacobs - that's an excellent write-up. We've currently implemented your first solution, but the visitor looks interesting.
You are right that getting the 'Fruit' to process itself is inappropriate - the actual processing is quite complicated with many dependencies. Thanks!